# Create database for unit testing in sqlite

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a simple class driven sqlite app. Basically, I want to run unit tests for it, but I haven't been able to so far.

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, dbname='mydb.db'):    
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        except:
            print('Error')
        finally:
            pass
```

Any class would use it then:

```
class Hello:
    def hi(self):
        db = DB() # Create db or connect to existing one
        cursor = db.connection.cursor()
```

Now, when testing, I pass on a test database:

```
db = DB('test.db')
#create datatabase here and all works fine
h = Hello()
```

Now, h makes use of mydb.db, instead of test.db. How does one go out about testing the above structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the instance of your `DB` class (`db`) you would need to feed the instance to your `Hello` class. Try:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, dbname='mydb.db'):    
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        except:
            print('Error')
        finally:
            pass

class Hello:
    def hi(self, db=DB()): # we make it have a default db of DB() (which in turn defaults to 'mydb.db')
        # db = DB() # Create db or connect to existing one
        # ^^ we remove this line because now this is the default
        cursor = db.connection.cursor()

db = DB('test.db') # this makes an instance of your DB class and calls it "db"
h = Hello(db) # now we need to feed this instance
```

Although this probably isn't the best way to go about it. You would likely benefit more from having a single class with methods because your second class is basically useless and is very closely related to your first class anyways:

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, dbname='mydb.db'):    
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        except:
            print('Error')
        finally:
            pass

    def hello(self): # making a method instead
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()

db = DB('test.db') # this makes an instance of your DB class and calls it "db"
db.hello() # call our method
```

## EDIT

I missed something originally that I found from testing my code. Your code should work fine, but you need to call the method you've made! Try this:

```
import sqlite3

class DB:
    def __init__(self, dbname='mydb.db'):
        try:
            self.connection = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        except:
            print('Error')
        finally:
            pass

class Hello:
    def hi(self):
        db = DB('test.db')
        cursor = db.connection.cursor()

db = DB('test.db')
h = Hello() # make our instance
h.hi() # use the method "hi" associated with the class (our function name within the class)
```

Comment: It's usually a good idea to test the code using a temporary database. Sqlite's [in-memory database](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) is helpful here.

Comment: @ralex thanks for adding more info! I think I figured it out with my edit though, OP never called the `hi` method of the `Hello` class

Comment: @Reedinationer thanks. The second approach is behaving exactly like what I am having right now. For testing purposes yes having everything in one class makes it easier but was wondering if I can keep the structure. Let me try your first approach again

Comment: @Reedinationer thanks for trying but it is not picking up db_test.db at all

Comment: @NieSelam How do you know it doesn't pick it up? Are you doing anything with the cursor that results in data being printed to the console? In the second example the line `db = DB()` within the `Hello` class would default to the value "mydb.db". You would need to change it to `db = DB('test.db')`

Comment: @Reedinationer my tests fail because there is data in db.db, while test.db have no data. db = DB() # Create db or connect to existing one in hi() method initializes it with db.db still, not test.db. I have decided to go with database path declaration which I overwrite from test.py now

Comment: @NieSelam Wouldn't it work with how I've edited the second example now? If you are trying to have `Hello` connect to "test.db" you would need to supply that information, since it will default to "mydb.db"